# Items not showing up in the RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an `Activity` that has a `RecyclerView` in the `layout`, i want to show some data in this `layout`  with a `RecyclerView`, the thing is that when i enter to the `Activity` the data is not visible and is empty.The data is collected with the help of a `java class` named `"recyclerViewModel"`, here i set a constructor with 6 `variables`, then i create in the `activity` code an `Arraylist` of this `class` and i create a total of 3 `objects` in a fast way with a `for` and `arrays` `(setDataRecycler method).` This 3 `objects`  have the 6 `variables` every one, every object means "a profile". The `objects` are saved in the `ArrayList` and the objective is to show them , as i said, in the `RecyclerView`

Activity java code:

```
package com.example.calculoimcwithui;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Profiles extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<recyclerViewModel> data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiles);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        data = new ArrayList<recyclerViewModel>();
        setDataRecycler();
        recyclerViewAdapter adapter = new recyclerViewAdapter(this,data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    private void setDataRecycler () {
        String [] nombres = {"Rober","Carlos","Laura"};
        String [] edades = {"16","16","21"};
        String [] alturas = {"178","180","162"};
        String [] pesos = {"72","68","54"};
        String [] afs = {"Bastante","Mucha","Bastante"};
        String [] generos = {"Hombre","Hombre","Mujer"};
        for (int i = 0; i<nombres.length;i++) {
            data.add(new recyclerViewModel(nombres[i],edades[i],alturas[i],pesos[i],afs[i],generos[i]));

        }
    }
}
```

Activity xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Profiles">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="399dp"
        android:layout_height="627dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.452" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerView Adapter:

```
package com.example.calculoimcwithui;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.calculoimcwithui.R;
import com.example.calculoimcwithui.recyclerViewModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recyclerViewAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<recyclerViewModel> data;

    public recyclerViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<recyclerViewModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;

    }
    @NonNull
    @Override

    public recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewmodel,parent,false);

        return  new recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        holder.age.setText(data.get(position).getAge());
        holder.height.setText(data.get(position).getAltura());
        holder.weight.setText(data.get(position).getPeso());
        holder.af.setText(data.get(position).getAf());
        holder.gender.setText(data.get(position).getGenero());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView age;

        TextView height;
        TextView weight;
        TextView af;
        TextView gender;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            age = itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
            height = itemView.findViewById(R.id.height);
            weight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.weight);
            af = itemView.findViewById(R.id.af);
            gender = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gender);

        }
    }


}
```

recyclerViewModel java code

```
package com.example.calculoimcwithui;

public class recyclerViewModel {

    String name;
    String age;
    String altura;
    String peso;
    String af;
    String genero;

    public recyclerViewModel(String name, String age, String altura, String peso, String af, String genero) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.af = af;
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge () {
        return age;
    }
    public String getAltura () {
        return  altura;
    }
    public String getPeso () {
        return peso;
    }

    public String getAf () {
        return af;
    }
    public String getGenero () {
        return genero;
    }
}
```

RecyclerView Model card

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="441dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="486dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/recCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
                android:text="Nombre"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.373" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="Edad"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.673" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/af"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
                android:text="Af"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.234" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/weight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
                android:text="Peso"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.673" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="136dp"
                android:text="Genero"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.663" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/height"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
                android:text="Altura"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.244" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I checked that the `getItemCount` method in the adapter class was actually returning the correct size, also the `width` and `height` of the `RecyclerView` and i checked that they are not in `wrap_content`. Also the number of items, i checked that the `xml` inflated file was the correct one, i checked the `setLayoutManager` method, ensuring that is writed, i do not know exactly what i can do more. (The app works fine, it does not throw any error, but the problem is that.)

Comment: The model card item height has a match_parent height, that should be wrap_content instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how you set up the XML for each row/card in the RecyclerView.

First, you need to change the height of the parent `ConstraintLayout` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. The height of a given row should not try to match the height of the parent recycler view, it should be just large enough to show its content. This will be enough to show all the cards, but the layouts will have a lot of white space because of the CardView margins (next part).

Second, you have some large hard-coded margins in the `CardView` itself that are most likely not what you want. These will result in huge cards with a lot of empty space. If you change the width there to `match_parent` and the height to `wrap_content` and remove the really large top/bottom margins you will see all three cards easily visible next to each other.

You may need to adjust the layout to get things looking the way you want within each card still, but they all show up. Hard-coding margins like 140dp is usually a red flag that you aren't using the ConstraintLayout properly.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Result of your demo code with those changes:

[image: recycler view]

Comment: Correct, this solved the problem and also helped me to understand some basic things about xml that i thought i knew. Thanks man, you really helped me :).